# Single-click instead of double-click to edit fields in inline editing (not using inputfield)

Tags: visualforce

is it possible to single-click to edit a field in Visualforce? I want to do it while in detail mode/inline edit mode. So basically change the behavior of being able to edit just by single clicking the field, instead of double clicking?

Comment: Just about anything is possible. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

This is still an Idea over Ideaexchange portal.

Request you to upvote [this Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Zo0PAAS) to get it considered by Product teams at Salesforce.

The main objectives of this idea is:

1. Keep double-clicking as a selection tool
2. For inline editing, hover over the field as now to bring up the pencil icon, and then click(single click) on the pencil to edit the field.